# mongodb operator deployment in openshift "Failed to apply default image tag "/:4.2.6" invalid reference format"

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, openshift, openshift-origin, okd

Im referring to mongodb community operator from https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator and trying to deploy it in openshift or okd

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator.git
cd mongodb-kubernetes-operator 
kubectl create namespace mongodb
kubectl create -f deploy/operator/role.yaml --namespace mongodb
kubectl create -f deploy/operator/role_binding.yaml --namespace mongodb
kubectl create -f deploy/operator/service_account.yaml --namespace mongodb
kubectl create -f deploy/crds/mongodb.com_mongodb_crd.yaml --namespace mongodb

oc apply -f deploy/openshift/operator_openshift.yaml -n mongodb
oc apply -f deploy/crds/mongodb.com_v1_mongodb_openshift_cr.yaml -n mongodb
```

Operator pod is successfully running but mongodb replica set pods does not come up. Error is as follows

```
[kubenode@master mongodb-kubernetes-operator]$ oc get pods
NAME                                           READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
example-openshift-mongodb-0                    0/2       InvalidImageName   10         31m
mongodb-kubernetes-operator-66bfcbcf44-rqp5l   1/1       Running            0          32m


 Failed to apply default image tag "/:4.2.6": couldn't parse image reference "/:4.2.6": invalid reference format
```

[image]
Here as the error indicates it is pulling the wrong image and i tried to update the image using `oc edit statefulset.apps/example-openshift-mongodb`. Once I update the image name correctly and save, i dont see the changes saved. Please let me know what could be done to update the image to right one

**Operator Information**

- Operator Version: 0.3.0
- MongoDB Image used:  4.2.6

**Kubernetes Cluster Information**

```
[kubenode@master mongodb-kubernetes-operator]$ openshift version
openshift v3.11.0+62803d0-1

[kubenode@master mongodb-kubernetes-operator]$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.0+d4cacc0", GitCommit:"d4cacc0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-10-15T09:45:30Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11+", GitVersion:"v1.11.0+d4cacc0", GitCommit:"d4cacc0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-07T17:59:40Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that since mongo statefulset are created using operator and crd https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/ the changes done directly to statefulsets are not getting saved. Hence editing the the crd file that is https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/blob/master/deploy/crds/mongodb.com_v1_mongodb_openshift_cr.yaml has helped me to solve the issue.
Add a new line with `image: mongo:4.2.6` after line no 33 in the mongodb.com_v1_mongodb_openshift_cr.yaml and then deploy

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command to update the deployment image of mongo

```
kubectl set image deployment/deployment-name contianerame=image:tag
```

in your case you can see clearly there is an issue with the tag of MongoDB image you tried to update

```
Failed to apply default image tag "/:4.2.6": couldn't parse image reference "/:4.2.6": invalid reference format
```

you can also update the image by editing the deployment or statefulsets

kubectl edit `deployment or statefulsets` `name of deployment or statefulsets`

Comment: Thanks but as i mentioned in the question , i have already tried this and its not working because whatever changes done to it are not getting saved

Comment: that is not getting saved may be due to a mistake or wrong alue of image.